# what is the best approach to follow when need to share react state among different components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a situation it is I have a component that i want it to be the component that holds the the state for the application and it has no children and I want other components in other routes to be connected the the first component state .

i will give you an example of what i mean :

```
//this is the stateful component 
class A extends React.Component{ 
  state ={
    data:{}
  };

  render(){
   return (
    <div>
     {Object.keys(this.state.data).map(key=> <h1>{this.state.data[key]}</h1>)}
     <Link to="/routeB">Button</Link>
    </div>
   );
  }
}

class B extends React.Component{
//here i want to display data from component A state
}

class C extends React.Component{
//here i want to control the state of component A consider this component 
//to be a control panel for the user 
}
```

i know that if the 3 components have any kind of relationship i could pass props 
till i got what i need but i can't figure out what to here as the 3 components didn't have any relationship

excuse me for my English and please consider that every component lives in its own route

Answer (score 1):

For me, a flux approach is the best approach, and the best implementation is [Redux](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react). You should take a look to it

Comment: I personally like mobX as well

Comment: I knew about Redux but is there is no solution here because i want to use a library that use the component state and  I can't handle that with Redux

Comment: @MickFeller Nice!, never heard of it, I'll definitively take a look to it.

Comment: MobX is a bit easier if you ask me actually redux is being replaced slowly if we have to go by this article: https://react-etc.net/entry/rip-redux-dan-abramov-announces-future-fetcher

Comment: @MostafaHesham why you can't handle states with redux?, that's it's purpose, I know it's not that easy to implement and use, but is a really good library

Comment: @MostafaHesham redux uses an application state / store so as long as the routes are in the same application redux can help you. Even if they wouldn't be in the same application you can setup redux in a way that multiple applications can talk to it if I'm not mistaken

Comment: @MickFeller thank you!, I see why it's being replaced and getting obsolete, when I got started with React I found Redux as the best and most popular option for handling states, but I always found it a little difficult to learn, It's good to see that the world is moving forward and we're getting better options

Comment: @GustavoTopete i want to sync the state with firebase and I use a library re-base for that and it uses the original state for that

Comment: @MickFeller I have heard about Mobx  but never tried it but i think Redux is a good library for handling the state it is every where even in a not react website .

Comment: Wow it is from the same man who created redux thanks for the information